# How Does SnapChat Send Data To Other Devices?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm interesting to know how SnapChat sends data to other mobile devices. For example does it send the data to a server that then stores it to be downloaded or does it send the data directly to the device via an in build ios function?

I am interested in the whole process of sending data between devices but I am not sure if I need to go down the web route via a server.

Thanks

Comment: Snapchat and instagram are billion dollar companies with massive backend data servers to which ios devices communicate to get to pics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer: snapchat surely uses a server to send the data to and the recipient has to download it from there.

here is a tutorial for how to use push notifications on ios (which is what you want to do, i think):
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

greetings

Comment: Hi, a family member mentioned that Snapchat don't store any picture data which I thought was a bit strange because I hadn't heard of a p2p function to deal with the issue. I would imagine like you mentioned that Snapchat must have a server to pass the information on.

Answer (score 2):

As @CodeOnTheFloor mentions it uses Apple push notifications ( no equivalent of Android  service to poll server)  on iOS.  However this does not mean it has to use a central server to distribute the image data (although I suspect it does).  It must use a central server at some stage though, even if the distribution is peer to peer ( which I doubt) a server is required to match users to IP addresses for the connection stage.